# socket.io determine if already connected to server

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am looking for a way on the client side to determine if I am already connected to a server via socket.io. I notice that after I am already connected and later try a `io.connect(url)` from elsewhere, no events are fired (connecting, connect, error, connect error, connect_failed, reconnecting) or failure occurs etc.

Is there some way / event to indicate that I am already connected?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to maintain state using the socket events: `connect`, `disconnect` and `error`. Keep a connected variable around and set it to true on the `connect` event and false on the `disconnect` event.

But if you don't want to do that, the socket has `connected` and `disconnected` variables on it (don't ask me why there are two). You can see the source [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.js).